# How to add different field values in views?

Tags: views, entities

I have two contents *A* and *B*. I have created a view for A, I need a one of field value from *B* in my *A view*.

I have referred some tutorials, they are suggesting relationship by using entity reference field.

Actually in my content *B* there is no any *entity reference* fields. In content *B* I have only two fields one is *title* and other one is *plain text*. How can I overcome this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

create a block view of content B By overiding fields and render a content of block in A's view page.

Comment: @ Vicky 8888 - thanks for your response i will check with this..

Comment: @ Vicky8888 - i am creating a view for B how can i give the option overiding fields and how can i give render option in A view page

Comment: Create a View Of content B/then Add fields Like title and plain text/then click on the title field a dialogue box will open there is an select box at the top,for[all displays] change this to for[change This block overide] you have to repeat the same step for plain text field

Comment: @ Vicky8888 - yeah i have given then how to cal the plain text value in view A

Comment: for calling block of view B in A  you must knw how to over ride view template file ,create a template file of view A then invoke the block in any region where you want to place the content of the block by using this code:

Comment: $block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'block_id'');
print render($block['content']);

Comment: another option is configure the path of block to view page  A ..add manually  block B to the view page of A

Comment: @  Vicky8888 - without Using block we can create?

Comment: I have told you the simplest method ,i think you are new in drupal in evening i will post you the another answer, keep searching on google whatever i told you in this post till evening

Comment: @ Vicky8888 - I got solution by following this link  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPQZLt3LHTY&hd=1 Thanks for your reply and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Field of content B is displaying in the field list of view, after finding that you can easily add in the view. You can select the filter option of content type too.

Comment: @ Arti prasad - Thanks for your response, I am calling that value from content B i am created a view for A,field is displaying in list when i am selecting it in view it is not displaying any data.